# update / fix for InputChannel is not initialized android open bug?

Tags: android, openbugs

Any update on the following Android open bug,

```
04-16 16:12:24.585 28935-28935/ssdsor.qusdse.kalsdsadrket E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ssdsor.qusdse.kalsdsadrket, PID: 28935
    java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized.
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.<init>(InputEventReceiver.java:70)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:6067)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:628)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3187)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I see this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/37018931)  and may one ask the same on StackOverflow.But no fix any were.Is this bug under treatment or still open?